# How do I turn the Result type into something useful?

Tags: range, d

I wanted a list of numbers:

```d
auto nums = iota(0, 5000);
```

Now `nums` is of type `Result`. It cannot be cast to `int[]`, and it cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for `int[]`.

It's not very clear from [the docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#iota) how to actually use an `iota` as a range. Am I using the wrong function? What's the way to make a "range" in D?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`iota`, like many functions in Phobos, is lazy. Result is a promise to give you what you need when you need it but no value is actually computed yet. You can pass it to a `foreach` statement for example like so:

```d
import std.range: iota;
foreach (i ; iota(0, 5000)) {
    writeln(i);
}
```

You don't need it for a simple foreach though:

```d
foreach (i ; 0..5000) {
    writeln(i);
}
```

That aside, it is hopefully clear that `iota` is useful by itself. Being lazy also allows for costless chaining of transformations:

```d
/* values are computed only once in writeln */
iota(5).map!(x => x*3).writeln;
// [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]
```

If you need a "real" list of values use `array` from `std.array` to delazify it:

```d
int[] myArray = iota(0, 5000).array;
```

As a side note, be warned that the word `range` has a specific meaning in D that isn't "range of numbers" but describes a model of iterators much like generators in python. `iota` is a range (so an iterator) that produced a range (common meaning) of numbers.